# telegram bot stopped responding with no errors in apache log file

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I was testing my bot (which is written in python and served via Apache on a vps by digital ocean) and it suddenly stopped responding. I checked Apache's error logs file but there were nothing relevant. so there were no errors.
Then I reassigned webhook( by deleting and setting it again) and everything came back to normal.
This accident reduced my trust on reliability of the bot :(
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfohttps://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) before reset it next time. See following example:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]